# Limit of an Expectation with a Poisson process

Tags: real-analysis, probability, limits, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda>0$ on a probability space $( \Omega, P, \mathcal{F})$; in particular
$$
P (X_t = k) = e^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}, \quad k \in \mathbb{N}_0.
$$
Additionally assume that $Y$ is a bounded random variable, not necessarily independent of $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$.

> Is it possible to evaluate $$\lim_{ t \downarrow 0 } E \left( \frac{1_{\{X_t = 1\}}}{t} Y\right) \quad ?$$

It is easy to see that
$$
\lim_{ t \downarrow 0 } E \left( \frac{1_{\{X_t = 1\}}}{t} \right) = \lim_{ t \downarrow 0} \frac{e^{-\lambda t } \lambda t}{t} = \lambda.
$$
But what can be said about the product? For every fixed $\omega \in \Omega$
$$
\frac{1_{\{X_t = 1\}}}{t} Y
$$
is either $0$ or $Y/t$, and it seems that dominated convergence theorem is not applicable. It may be helpful to mention that
$$
\lim_{ t \downarrow 0 }P(X_t > \varepsilon) = 0
$$
for any $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: $\frac{E[|\mathbb{1}_{X_t=1}Y|]}{t} \leq \frac{M E[|\mathbb{1}_{X_t=1}|]}{t} = \frac{M e^{-\lambda t}\lambda t}{t} \to 0$ by boundedness of the r.v. $Y$.

Comment: @fGDu94 what you wrote actually converges to $M \lambda$ as $t \downarrow 0$.

Comment: I think in this case you can't really say much then, you can say the limit is less than $M\lambda$ in absolute value. You can definitely prove that it exists (as we just did).